# json - look for value and key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm quite new to programming and I been googling but couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for.

ok I send a request by ajax and I get response similar to this (the original json is much more complicated)

```
{
"shelf": {
    "genre": {
        "title1": {
            "date": "date",
            "author": "name",
            "featured": "N"
        }
        "title2": {
            "date": "date",
            "author": "name",
            "featured": "Y"
}}}
```

now I need to do find a "book" which is featured. So I have been looking for a way to look for featured = Y and get it's title in this case "title2".

The best way I could figure out is that when I create the json (in php) when something is featured I can create a new key => value at the same level as "shelf"

```
"shelf": {
    "genre": {
        "title1": {
             /.../
        }
        "title2": {
             /.../
}}}
"featured": {
    "genre": "featuredTitle"
    "genre2":"featuredTitle2"
}}}
```

and then access it in javascript like this:

```
response.featured['genre'];
```

and then get all the data by going to

```
response.shelf.genre.title
```

but there must be a better way to do it... this gets very messy when the json is very  complicated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. You can loop through a JSON object quite easily, JSON is a very friendly format.

```
var genres = response.shelf.genre;

for (title in genres) {

  if (genres.hasOwnProperty(item)) {

    var bookTitle = title;
    var featured = genres[title].featured;
  }
}
```

The `hasOwnProperty` is a safety feature you should always use when looping through a JSON object. You can find out [more about it here](http://brianflove.com/2013/09/05/javascripts-hasownproperty-method/).

#### More on JSON

JSON solely consists of Javascript Objects and Arrays, one or the other. So even if the stack is complicated, you can always parse it by traversing either an object or an array, and so long as you know the structure of the JSON, it is easy to parse.

```
// Objects:
myJSON.subObject.anotherSubobject.andAnotherOne;

// Arrays:
myJSON[0]; // accesses first item in array...
myJSON.subObject[2]; // accesses third item in the subObject array.
```

Comment: ohh great! that does the job very well and it's much simpler than I expected! I will accept in 10 mins (it doesn't let me do it now) thanks !

Comment: Thanks. Yes become a master at JSON - its beats the pants off XML.